# Can't convert to String

Tags: php

UPDATE: Turns out I forgot to make it global, the function. My bad.

New problem, though. Turns out it can't convert something to a string apparently?
I'm not sure what's going on anymore, I'm sorry.

Comment: try to remove the `count(*)`, and just `*`

Comment: That didn't do anything sadly. Actually that would break my code for what I'm trying to do entirely, so that's not a great idea either way. It doesn't solve my initial problem either, though.

Comment: which line is 52?

Comment: using `$this` you have to be calling the function from within its class

Comment: which framework you are using ?

Comment: Can you show some more of your actual code? In your previous question, it looked a lot like this was a method in a class, can you show that class?

Answer (score 0):

Either your function is in a differt file that you do not include in that script, you are calling it.
Or your function is part of a class, so you have to instanciate that class and call your function from there.

As far as we do not know more about, where is your function (and in what context) and where is your call-code, one cannot say more.

Simple: The part of code what calls your function does not know your function.

Answer (score 0):

$this is used for pointing class or instance variables but for function you can to use  $self  and second eror is coz of ur bindValue statement
 format of bindValue is:  bindValue("placeholder",variable,parameter)

```
  EXAMPLE:-
  <?php
  $username = "user";
  $password= "password"
  //now
  $st = $self->connection->prepare($sql_statement);
  $st->bindValue("username", :username , PDO::PARAM_STR); // for integer value it will (PDO::PARAM_INT)
  ?>
```